# Android Facebook Login setReadPermissions not working

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Initially my code worked perfectly. Then yesterday I realized that login via the Facebook button, setReadPermissions asks only public profile, ignoring email, friend list.... I have another project should this code works perfectly. You know tell me why?

This is part of my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    ...
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    facebook();
    ...
}

private void facebook(){
        facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_friends,user_birthday"));
        getLoginDetails(facebookLoginButton);
    }

protected void getLoginDetails(final LoginButton login_button) {

        // Callback registration
        login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {
                final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        login_result.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {

                                    System.out.println("Questo è l'object"+object);
                                    System.out.println("Questo è il response"+response);

                                    System.out.println("Questo è il Nome"+object.getString("name"));
                                    System.out.println("Questo è il id"+object.getString("id"));
                                    System.out.println("Questo è il email"+object.getString("email"));

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name, birthday,picture,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // code for cancellation
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                //  code to handle error
            }
        });

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // Set the access token using
                // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
                //System.out.println("Questo è accesso token "+currentAccessToken);
                System.out.println("Questo è accesso OLDtoken "+oldAccessToken);
            }
        };

        // If the access token is available already assign it.
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        System.out.println("Questo è accesso token "+accessToken);   

    }
```

In other project, this code work perfectly. I thought it's a Facebook app problem, permissions problem, but also with my admin account it get me only public profile. Help me pls.

Comment: have you tried to rebuild/clean build?also unistall first from emulator or device

Comment: Yes, not work, i tried all test..

Comment: `setPublishPermissions` isn’t even in the code you have shown.

Comment: oh sorry, it's setReadPermissions, i have corrected

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I find out that when I created the button it was like

```
private Button loginButton;
```

but it should be

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
```

and in your case is the Facebook Button.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Right now `setReadPermissions` is deprecated, so `setPermissions` must be used in such way:

```
 facebookLoginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", /*etc as a string permissions*/,"user_birthday"));
```

**Old answer:**

You're using an array as a list by passing it only one argument.

```
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_friends,user_birthday"));
```

Don't know why facebook understand even the first element. Instaed you should use this:

```
  facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", /*etc as a string permissions*/,"user_birthday"));
```

Comment: Use setPermissions, setReadPermissions is deprecated